# Any working example for org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.command.diff.DiffCommand

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to find out differences between two revisions using org-netbeans-lib-cvsclient-RELEASE712.jar.

any working example?

```
    DiffCommand diffCommand = new DiffCommand();
    diffCommand.setRecursive(true);
    diffCommand.setRevision1("rel-2230");
    diffCommand.setRevision2("rel-2240");
    diffCommand.setFiles(new File[]{new File("D:/test/")});
    diffCommand.setBuilder(new SimpleDiffBuilder(em, diffCommand));

    try {
        System.out.println(diffCommand.getCVSCommand());

        cvsClient.executeCommand(diffCommand, opts);
        Set files = cvsClient.getAllFiles(new File("D:/test/"));

    } catch (CommandException | AuthenticationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```